# Edit a Push notification in a running journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

How can I edit my push notification in a running journey? We were about to start a journey and we would like to configure some random push message first and the day before the push goes we would like to change to actual message. How can i edit a push notification in a running journey. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify push message in Journey Builder once journey was activated (without creating new version of the journey).
What you can do is to create code snippets in Content Builder and call it from your push message:

```
%%=ContentBlockbyId(384201)=%%
or
%%=ContentBlockbyKey("myContentBlock")=%%
```

This way Journey Builder will always retrieve content of the code snippet before each send, so you can change you message any time.

Comment: Thank you @Ros Haitovich. When a customer opens the push we are showing them a cloud page, can we also update that once it is configured with different cloud page in journey?

Comment: You can create another code snippet and reference it in page url textbox, generally speaking ampscript should work in every message content related configurations. Not perfect but sometimes this can be very handy to quickly update message.